# VS used to point in solution explorer to a hyperlink or anything to make mapping easier

Tags: view, crash, screen, floating, reboot

Not sure how to explain this but before my PC crashed, my VS was setup in a way that when I clicked on a   etc, it used to show the path of where that image/file was so I simply clicked on it on the right side of solution explorer and I would be able to update that file within it's location. Is it an option on VIEW that I need to click or how do I get that window back?

Sorry if I don't make sense, maybe the pic will help

On the red bottom right side, the window would be dock there that made updating a line easier

tried many options but my expectation was to see that missing screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPe3C.png)